# Clojure :gen-class not working in Java app

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen, clojure-java-interop

This is my myns/junk.clj file

```
(ns myns.junk
  (:gen-class
    :name booklist.util
    :methods [[sq [int] int]]))

(defn sq [x] (* x x))
```

I'm running `lein ubserjar` without issue.  I've imported the generated jar in my java application, and then ran this

```
package javaapplication1;

import booklist.util;

public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        util u = new util();
        System.out.println(u.sq(45));   
    }
}
```

which produces error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: sq (myns.junk/-sq not defined?)
>       at booklist.util.sq(Unknown Source)
>       at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:14)
>   C:\Users\X750JA\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

What am I missing, and ideally, are there any kind of docs available which explain this stuff in detail?

---

Edit, per Alejandro's answer, I tried this

```
(ns myns.junk
  (:gen-class
    :name booklist.util
    :methods [[sq [int] int]]))

(defn sq [x] (* x x))

(defn -sq
  "A Java-callable wrapper around the 'sq' function."
  [n]
  (sq n))
```

which now produces error

> Exception in thread "main" clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (2) passed to: junk/-sq
>       at clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity(AFn.java:429)
>       at clojure.lang.AFn.invoke(AFn.java:36)
>       at booklist.util.sq(Unknown Source)
>       at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:14)
>   C:\Users\X750JA\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

---

What I wound up with was this

```
(ns myns.junk
  (:gen-class
    :name booklist.util
    :methods [#^{:static true} [sq [int] int]]))

(defn -sq [x] (* x x))

(-sq 7) ; works - 49
```

So it seems I need to declare the method as static, and define the actual method to have a leading dash in the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing something like this in your clojure file

```
(defn -sq
  "A Java-callable wrapper around the 'sq' function."
  [n]
  (sq n))
```

Also, you'll need to define the method as static.

I think the canonical documentation is here: https://clojure.org/reference/compilation

Comment: Thanks for the response - I updated my question with that attempt - it seems Java still doesn't like it :(

Comment: @AdamRackis I think it should actually be a static method